# How to properly determine that the end-of-input has been reached in a QTCPSocket?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, eof

I have the following code that reads from a QTCPSocket:

```
QString request;

while(pSocket->waitForReadyRead())
{
    request.append(pSocket->readAll());
}
```

The problem with this code is that it reads all of the input and then pauses at the end for 30 seconds. (Which is the default timeout.)

What is the proper way to avoid the long timeout and detect that the end of the input has been reached? (An answer that avoids signals is preferred because this is supposed to be happening synchronously in a thread.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to be sure is when you have received the exact number of bytes you are expecting. This is commonly done by sending the size of the data at the beginning of the data packet. Read that first and then keep looping until you get it all. An alternative is to use a sentinel, a specific series of bytes that mark the end of the data but this usually gets messy.

Comment: Well, this is an HTTP request handler, so any HTTP request that sends the `Content-length` header will be easy to handle.

Comment: You also need to add some timeouts, becouse if someone would attack your service, it could send Content-length, and send no data. I gues that 30 seconds timeout is to much. Maybe you should do like try max 3 retries of 5 second timeout, and assume that connection is broken

Comment: +1 This is THE correct answer. This is TCP, a streaming protocol. You must interpret the stream to determine whether the input has been completely transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a situation like an HTTP response that doesn't contain a Content-Length, and you know the other end will close the connection once the data is sent, there is an alternative solution.

1. Use socket.setReadBufferSize to make sure there's enough read buffer for all the data that may be sent.
2. Call socket.waitForDisconnected to wait for the remote end to close the connection
3. Use socket.bytesAvailable as the content length

This works because a close of the connection doesn't discard any buffered data in a QTcpSocket.

Comment: A bit of extra info: add the Connection: close header to your HTTP request to ask the server to explicitly close the connection when it's done sending data.